# ArrayList .add method missing

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello I have the following problem: I want to create an arraylist and want to add some items.
But somehow the .add Method is not there.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Chairing{
     private int numbers;
     ArrayList<Chairs>myList = new ArrayList<Chairs>();
     myList.add(5,new Chairset("10"));
     }

public class Chair{
  int price;
  String info;

    public Chair(int price, Chairset c){
    this.price = price;
    info = c.getInfo();
    }
}

public class Chairset{
    String info;

    public Chairset(String id){
    id = info;
    }
}
```

For some Reasons I can't add something in my new ArrayList. The constructor for Chair needs a price and an object Chairset. Chairset needs an id.

Comment: I will just emphasize `ArrayList<Chairs>` and `public class Chairset`.

Comment: Why is there an `import` statement inside a class definition?

Comment: `!Chairset instanceof Chair`

Comment: to simplify what @SotiriosDelimanolis said, you are trying to add an object of type Chairset to an arraylist of type Chair

Comment: Why is `myList.add(5,new Chairset("10"));` directly inside a class definition?

Comment: This seems to be an uncompilable mush of fragments of code

Comment: Your problem is coming from a lot of syntax errors. You should remake your classes and compile along the way so that you know each class is correctly done. Even better is to use an integrated development environment (IDE) for java such as Eclipse, NetBeans, or Intellij that will help you with syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your classes have no common type, the tightest generic bound the list can have would be Object. Either use a marker interface, or notice the similarity between Chair and Chairset and have one extend the other - giving them a common type.

Also note that the line in your code where you add to the list is not in a legal location - it must be within a method.

Try this:

```
public class Chairing {
    private int numbers;
    List<Chairset> myList = new ArrayList<Chairset>();
    public void someMethod() {
        myList.add(5,new Chairset("10"));
    }
}

public class Chair extends Chairset {
    int price;

    public Chair(int price, Chairset c){
        super(c.getInfo());
        this.price = price;
    }
}

public class Chairset {
    String info;

    public Chairset(String id){
        id = info;
    }
}
```